# How should this addition's concrete foundation be reinforced, if at all?

Tags: concrete, foundation, addition

I'm asking about what looks like a DIY concrete foundation under an extension. There's a few issues with the foundation, but given how long it's lasted, I'm not sure it needs to be made sturdier. Looking for answers here on how, if at all, this should be reinforced.

Background: House was built in the early 60s, addition and foundation in question was build in the late 80s, so this foundation has been where it is for over 30 years already. This is in a mild cool climate of Pennsylvania, where ground freezes but not that deeply. The addition is off the long side of a ranch-style house and the whole house is 1 story tall. The original house has a block foundation and basement, while the addition has nothing under it but this concrete. The floor and walls in the additional all look great and are level. One of the concrete sections outside has settled in a way that leads to puddling, which I'll highlight in photos below.

---

Here's an overall look at foundation for this addition. As I describe in a later photo, the foam board to the left is covering a small cavity under this concrete foundation, where a functioning wellhead is. The wellhead is accessible just 1-2ft in that cavity. The cavity overall is no more than 3ft deep by 3ft wide and 2ft tall, quite a bit smaller than that I think. In that cavity, it's hard to tell what is concrete and what is crusty soil, without poking at it.
[image: concrete foundation angle side view]

Side views showing the foundation is not plumb nor straight:
[image: concrete foundation side view not plumb]
[image: concrete foundation side view not straight]

Some smaller issues with the foundation: wood not protected with flashing or caulk, wood left in the concrete in contact with the ground when it was poured.
[image: exposed wood siding on foundation]
[image: wood embedded in concrete foundation]

Someone I spoke with asked how the concrete foundation connects with the rest of the house in terms of framing. That's hard for me to tell because the interior is all finished where the two parts of the house connect. However they're connected, it seems well done, because 30+ years later the door between the original house and the addition all closes well and both sides have level and flawless-looking floors.

Here's a picture of the end of the concrete foundation, with the original block foundation under the wood porch. (The rigid foam next to the foundation was used to cover up a well head, which was actually under the addition, still accessible since the concrete foundation has a gap under it over there.)
[image: old and new foundations meet]

Lastly, here's pictures of that concrete which is exposed to the outdoors on top. You can see some settling, or bad grading in the first place, leads to puddling toward the house. I plan to put an overhang on top of this area, to cover the two doors in this photo, so that should fix the water issue. This just gives a sense of some but not severe settling over 30 years:
[image: settling leading to puddling]
[image: foundation overall for addition]

Does this addition's 30+ year-old foundation look like it needs to be reinforced somehow? If so, what kind of reinforcement would you expect, and what kind of expert should I shop around for? I'm not familiar with concrete so any insights are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you notice any minor cracks on the drywall inside?  Most homes do have them when the house is settling a few years after being built, but asking about new cracks.  If no cracks then would think most of those problems more cosmetic.

Comment: The house is new to me, so it could have been painted recently (though no smell/sign of that) and I wouldn't notice the cracks yet. That said, there are minimal cracks, just a little between wall and ceiling. I know the windows in the addition are many years old, and they still open well and don't show any problems with their framing.

Comment: Other than the pooling by the door, is there anything that leads you to believe there are problems with the foundation?

Comment: @FreeMan only that it is clearly an amatuer job, according to a home inspector and my own view of it not having plumb or straight edges. The in-person opinions I got - not from masons - was that if it's kept the addition level and in tact for over a decade, it is unlikely to need any reinforcing. I don't know much about foundation issues or reinforcement, which led me to ask about it here.

Comment: Rent a concrete saw and cut some channels to drain the puddle(s). The rest is cosmetics, not function. Preferable to drain that even if planning a roof.