# What work is needed to resolve water issues related to this settling slab?

Tags: concrete, foundation, waterproofing, concrete-block

### Summary of issue

This house was built around 1960 on cinderblock foundation, and in 1980 an addition was built on [an apparently-DIY concrete slab foundation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/246811/how-should-this-additions-concrete-foundation-be-reinforced-if-at-all). Part of that concrete slab extends beyond the new room, serving as a kind of porch. That porch / outdoor concrete slab has a seam halfway through it, and the half closer to the house has settled and is now graded slightly toward the house, resulting in puddling. The other half of the porch has a good grade and drains/dries well. Here's a photo of the overall scene and the puddling near the house (this is hours after rainfall, where other surfaces already dried):

[image: zoom out of addition's slab foundation]

[image: slab foundation exposed as a porch]

[image: puddling on the porch]

[image: area puddling near house]

**My question** is what kind of work needs to be done to remedy the puddling and the mild basement water intrusion I think is associated with this. Is it basement waterproofing? Resurfacing the concrete slab part that has puddles? Demolition and redoing that section of the porch/slab? I am speaking with different contractors and getting different opinions, and I could use a more neutral answer.

The goals for the work is to prevent water damage to the house. A simple way to do that, which offers other benefits, is to add a roof section between the two reddoors in the photo above. Those doors connect the addition to a garage, and there are no indoor connections to the garage, so an overhead path would be nice and would keep rain off the slab. The issue with that solution is, we figure the slab should be level and 'fixed' before putting a post on it to support a roof extension.

### Where the slab meets the house

Contractors have been interested in how the slab connects to the house, and what kind of water we're seeing in the house. The next two photos zoom in on where this part of the slab connects to the house.

This photo is where the slab meets the garage. The garage is on cinderblock foundation but there is no basement, just a poured cement floor, with some cracks but nothing too notable after 60 years. I cannot fit a finger between the slab and garage foundation, but it does not seem to be sealed/caulked in any way.
[image: Slab meeting garage block foundation]

This photo shows the slab meeting the house itself. A couple of issues we see: the siding should not be so low to the ground, and the cement edges seem very DIY'd and insufficient. The area in the basement we occasionally see water is more or less right below/behind that wet spot. (We have checked the hose bib plumbing and there are no leaky pipes.)
[image: Slab meets house siding, over the basement where we occasionally see water]

### Basement moisture

Thankfully the basement is mostly dry. We've only been here for a few months, and we only saw water in this area during springtime - even in heavy rains, no water in the basement since it has been so dry. Our sump has also been at a very low water level all summer, even in heavy rain the pump does not need to run. That said, we want to keep it dry, and we do need to run a dehumidifier down there.

That said, when we did see water in the basement, it was a small amount (no more than a gallon) in spring a day after heavy rain. This is the area, right behind the puddling near the house on that porch slab. Despite that puddled water, this basement wall, window, and floor is dry.
[image: basement where water sometimes pools]

Zoom in of the window which was sealed off, presumably when the addition's slab blocked it off. I felt some moisture at the edge of this window when I'd last seen water on the basement floor, but it was hard to tell exactly where water came in.
[image: Sealed off basement window]

### The question

Reiterating my question above: What kind of approach is needed to durably prevent water issues with the foundation here? We'd like to extend the roof over this area but figure we need a level pad to do that on. Can this kind of slab porch be graded/resurfaced a little higher with a proper slope, without much demolition? Could it be long-lasting to build the roof over this area as-is, or with simple drainage channels cut into the slab where it puddles? Demolition and redoing that part of the porch feels risky - if it's not broke, don't fix it, and I don't want to mess with the functional foundation under the room that was added onto that DIY slab.

Comment: You might investigate concrete jacking to get that corner of the floor raised. You're right to want to fix the slope before putting a roof up - rain that misses the roof will still want to roll down hill and puddle there. What's the window block off made of?

Comment: @FreeMan I don't know what the window block-off is made of. I know it was painted over with some sort of sealant. I'll see if I can learn more from the previous owner. As for concrete jacking, thanks for the tip, I was not aware of that as an option.

Comment: Not sure how easy it would be to concrete jack an inside corner like that. You'd have to contact some companies to get quotes.

Comment: I suspect the original metal window frame is still there.  I see some rust stains around the bottom edge of the blocked-off window.  I wonder if removing the current seal, removing the metal window frame, and bricking that rectangle closed would be a better approach.  But I doubt that's the primary issue. / Where I live it's been an extraordinarily dry summer.  You could simulate a lot of rain, or wait until the weather changes, and then make your observations. / Have you checked that the faucet has no dripping, externally or just inside the siding? / Does a bit of leftover water come out ...

Comment: ... from the end of the hose? / Can you put some cement on the lowest part and slope it away from the house?  Maybe half an inch of extra height would be enough. / I agree that an awning wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: @aparente001 Interesting points about the window, will ask a contractor about that. We have checked that faucet for dripping, no issues there. As for cement sloping away from house, you can see some of that was already done around the edges where the puddling is. An inspector told me that was insufficient, the cement needs to be thicker and more continuous to be long lasting and effective - that's the kind of info I wanted to learn more about / confirm here, as I assess proposals from contractors.

Comment: In my previous house, we discovered a concrete patio under a mound of soil.  We moved the soil to a different bed.  We resurfaced the concrete, making it look better and also correcting the slope a bit.  I forget what product we bought but we mixed it by hand and used a long squeegee.  It worked well.

Comment: One contractor just suggested we chisel off the cement around the edges (which is already cracking), then build a graded/level flagstone or brick patio on top of the slabs. That way we don't disturb the slabs but do level it all out and make it look nicer. They suggested waiting a year or two first, marking where the two exposed slab sections meet and observing how much they heave or not during winter, as that informs how the top layer should be setup.